# Can Asterisk use GSM PCIe card for Dial out or Dial in?

Tags: asterisk, gsm

I want to know if it is possible to use asterisk to make calls through a PCIe Mobile Network card or a USB dongle  I'm Looking it's to use a GSM line dial out and dial in and only requires one GSM chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can
Options are:

Chan_dongle -  obsolete, may require older asterisk version to compile
Chan_modem - even older

Sip GSM gateways. External hardware devices accessible via network

Comment: Thank You that's help me !